# Background swipe handler to be cancelled on certain elements

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-mobile

I have this code on my website so you could go back/forward using swipe

```
$(function() {
  $(window).on("swipeleft", jqmForward)
           .on("swiperight", jqmBack);
});
```

The problem is it also goes back/forward when you try swiping on something that already has its own swipe handler (eg. a **3rd-party** slide gallery)

How do you make it work only at the "background" (to ignore certain elements that have its own swipe handler)?

**EDIT:** Simplified the code above, and I tried this but doesn't work (probably because I'm adding it to window not a single div)

```
$('.swiper-wrapper').off();
```

Comment: `$(window).not("skipThis").on(swipeleft, ....`

Comment: @Omar: Thanks but now it doesn't work at all (no errors either)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having a global variable `allowGlobalSwipe` and dynamically disabling it using Swiper API.

```
var allowGlobalSwipe = true; // <--

$(function() {
  $(window).on("swiperight", jqmBack);

  $('#slideContainer').swiper({
    onTouchStart: function () { allowGlobalSwipe = false; },   // <--
    onTouchEnd: function () { allowGlobalSwipe = true; }
  });
});

function jqmBack(e) {
  if (!allowGlobalSwipe) return;  // <--

  var prevpage = $('div.ui-page-active').prevAll('div[data-role="page"]');
  if (prevpage.length > 0)
    $.mobile.changePage($(prevpage[0]), { transition: "slide", reverse: true }, true, true);
}
```

Comment: You've implemented your own way to stop event propagation but one already exists. You should be able to select the elements you don't want to activate the global swipe and stop the propagation of `touchmove`: `$([some elements]).on("touchmove", function (event) {event.stopPropagation();})`. Other associated events are `touchstart` and `touchend`.

Comment: But I am using Swiper, not my own code. Or am I missing something?